# how to do a keyboard interrupt of Python3 code in Spyder

Tags: spyder, keyboardinterrupt

I have a simple but long loop in Python 3 that calls a simple function. I want to stop the execution, and that should be possible with Ctrl-C but that doesn't work. How to do this "manual keyboard interrupt"? I use Anconda3 for windows64, with Python 3.7.

Ctrl-C doesnt do anything, and also the red button in the IPython console doesn't do anything.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Python3.7
Created on Wed Jul 24 12:59:31 2019
This proves that Ctr C doesn't work in Spyder
@author: Rob
"""

#%% loop in main program

def hello():
    print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))

import time
nr = 0
while nr < 42:
    nr +=1
    hello()
    time.sleep(1)



#%% loop in function

def hello():
    nr = 0
    while nr < 42:
        nr +=1
        print('Hello Spyder '+str(nr))
        time.sleep(1)

import time
hello()
```

I expect the code to stop when using keyboard CTrl-C. But the code just keeps on executing til the end.

Answer (score 0):

probably already solved this yourself, but try this.

```
import time

i = 0

try:
    while i < 100:
        print (i)
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("interrupted")
```